# How to change linux terminal prompt to match ParrotOS

Tags: linux, bash, prompt, parrotsec

I know that terminal prompt can be changed using `PS1="prefix"` and I know how to set it permanently, that is not a problem. I am just wondering, how would I set it to look like in parrot OS?

Especially how would I make it multi-line and how would I create that nice arrow?

[image]

Comment: https://iamalipe.blogspot.com/2017/12/how-to-create-parrot-os-style.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my code (not exactly the same).

- To do the newline there is a `\n`
- The funny arrow is unicode a character (paste from web-lookup)
- The colour code have to be between `\[` and `\]`, to tell bash that they are zero width (so that it can do its stuff, like go to start of line. It is all done with [dead reckoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_reckoning).
- Codes like `\033[01;32m` are colour codes.

  ```
  if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
  else
      PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
  fi
  _PS1="$PS1"
  PS1='$(echo $title|sed -r -e "s/^(\S+)\$/[\1]/")'"${_PS1}\n#↳ "
  ```

Comment: The `title` variable is called but not set

Comment: @GillesQuenot Yes title evaluates no an empty string. But you can set it.

Answer (score 4):

Shell prompt recreation:

[image: Shell using ParrotOS-like prompt]

Create a file ~/.bash_prompt (or any name you like) and paste this code in it

```bsh
# Define some basic colors using tput (8-bit color: 256 colors)
red="\[$(tput setaf 160)\]"
bright_red="\[$(tput setaf 196)\]"
light_purple="\[$(tput setaf 60)\]"
orange="\[$(tput setaf 172)\]"
blue="\[$(tput setaf 21)\]"
light_blue="\[$(tput setaf 80)\]"
bold="\[$(tput bold)\]"
reset="\[$(tput sgr0)\]"

# Define basic colors to be used in prompt
## The color for username (light_blue, for root user: bright_red)
username_color="${reset}${bold}${light_blue}\$([[ \${EUID} == 0 ]] && echo \"${bright_red}\")";
## Color of @ and ✗ symbols (orange)
at_color=$reset$bold$orange
## Color of host/pc-name (blue)
host_color=$reset$bold$blue
## Color of current working directory (light_purple)
directory_color=$reset$light_purple
## Color for other characters (like the arrow)
etc_color=$reset$red
# If last operation did not succeded, add [✗]- to the prompt
on_error="\$([[ \$? != 0 ]] && echo \"${etc_color}[${at_color}✗${etc_color}]─\")"
# The last symbol in prompt ($, for root user: #)
symbol="${reset}${bold}${bright_red}$(if [[ ${EUID} == 0 ]]; then echo '#'; else echo '$'; fi)"


# Setup the prompt/prefix for linux terminal
PS1="${etc_color}┌─${on_error}[";
PS1+="${username_color}\u"; # \u=Username
PS1+="${at_color}@";
PS1+="${host_color}\h" #\h=Host
PS1+="${etc_color}]-[";
PS1+="${directory_color}\w"; # \w=Working directory
PS1+="${etc_color}]\n└──╼ "; # \n=New Line
PS1+="${symbol}${reset}";

export PS1
```

The comments should describe the code functionality sufficiently.
If you want to use this prompt automatically, add following code to your ~/.bashrc file

```bsh
# Use custom bash prompt (will execute .bash_prompt script)
if [ -f ~/.bash_prompt ]; then
  . ~/.bash_prompt
fi
```

Comment: Why the `+x` in the mode. It is not needed, and won't help. Did you test this bit?. (-1 for the `+x`, and +1 for the rest.)

Comment: Nicely done! Personally I'd echo `$?` instead of `✗`, though.  Not exactly what the OP asked for, but it adds a little more information.

Answer (score 2):

I might be a bit late to this post... but for anyone who finds it useful I've pasted the whole `.bashrc` file from ParrotOS [here](https://pastebin.com/71C1wEAB).

This is the bit you're interested in:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1="\[\033[0;31m\]\342\224\214\342\224\200\$([[ \$? != 0 ]] && echo \"[\[\033[0;31m\]\342\234\227\[\033[0;37m\]]\342\224\200\")[$(if [[ ${EUID} == 0 ]]; then echo '\[\033[01;31m\]root\[\033[01;33m\]@\[\033[01;96m\]\h'; else echo '\[\033[0;39m\]\u\[\033[01;33m\]@\[\033[01;96m\]\h'; fi)\[\033[0;31m\]]\342\224\200[\[\033[0;32m\]\w\[\033[0;31m\]]\n\[\033[0;31m\]\342\224\224\342\224\200\342\224\200\342\225\274 \[\033[0m\]\[\e[01;33m\]\\$\[\e[0m\]"
else
    PS1='┌──[\u@\h]─[\w]\n└──╼ \$ '
fi
```

Comment: Ironically, the actual ParrotOS code is inferior to the version in another answer where someone reverse engineered it from the screenshot.  (-:

Answer (score 0):

Get PS1 variable from Parrot OS via env, copy it to file and use on your other Linux.

So it could be like that:

```
echo "PS1=\"$PS1\"" > setPS1
```

and use this file as script in other Linux.
You may need to export the variable.
Setting it up in `~/.bashrc` would be easy.

Comment: Problem is that I don't have an instance of Parrot OS currently installed anywhere

Comment: @Koumakpet that means you can't permanently setup this variable. Or you can run the script each time you need.